# StorageFile methods that don't use a stream in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, stream, uwp

From what I understand a stream must be opened to allow your application to interact with the file system. But certain classes like `StorageFile` has methods that don't open a stream while still manipulating files stored on the computer like `CopyAsync` and `MoveAsync`. How is this possible?

Comment: You don't need to open (and read) a file to copy or move it. Search the web for "file system".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does offer methods to work with files, without opening them. Look at [`System.IO.File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). E.g. the `Exists`, `Copy` or `Delete` methods wont open the file.

However those functions are not async and will block your execution. But you can wrap them into a task and make those actions async.

```
var moveTask = Task.Run(() => File.Move("source", "Target"));
// Do something else
await moveTask;
```